# Can I found out that somebody killed my process?

Tags: scripts, kill, background-process

I have a script that I start in the background. Few hours later, process is not running anymore. Is there any way to find out that somebody killed my process and that it didn't die by itself?

Thanks a lof.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who wants to kill another users process would have to do this as superuser and you could observe the superuser switch in `/var/log/auth.log`. Finding a `sudo kill ...` there would be kind of the smoking gun. Other than that ... nope.

But you could run your script in the foreground maybe inside `screen`, and set *traps* for the kill signal and similar stuff. This would still not show you a `kill -9`, but make things more observable in general.